# Integral of sin(x)/sqrt(x) from 0 to \pi

Tags: integration

How to calculate improper integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin{t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt}$?

Comment: This is more suitable on M.SE.

Comment: Maybe the rush to downvote and close (excuse me, put "on hold") was a bit hasty... This is not an elementary integral; I see that it can be evaluated in terms of the complex error function, but I doubt that it can be simplified further.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I agree that the downvotes may have been hasty; I didn't downvote, but I easily could have. However questions like this about evaluating definite integrals seem to be more at home at math.SE (even quite difficult integrals, which often receive extremely impressive answers there!). So the best outcome may be for this question to be moved to math.SE.

Comment: Just asking WolframAlpha to compute it, turns up the link with Fresnel integrals.  Is there more to be said?

Comment: Meaning that Wolfram Alpha is capable of making the change of variable $x\mapsto x^2$ correctly. I can do that too, so I'm not impressed. "Is there more to be said?" is exactly the question asked by the OP. My guess is "No", but I have no proof that the answer is algebraicly independent with $e$ and $\pi$, so, if it is "not research level", it is not because it is *below* the current level of advanced research but because the current knowledge is severely insufficient to answer questions of this kind. If that is what was meant by those who voted to close, I agree.

Comment: @fedja: And where exactly does this question ask about independence from $e$ and $\pi$ and so on.  Maybe there is an interesting question to be asked here, but the question does not do this.  My guess based on the ``improper integral" in the question is that OP was perhaps worried about convergence, or how to compute it.  If someone wishes to edit and make an interesting question out of this, then I'm happy to vote to reopen.

Comment: @Lucia I do not mind closing it under the "Unclear what you are asking" pretext (because the way it is posed is so open to interpretation that one is limited only by his imagination and personal preferences when answering or up/downvoting). Moreover, I do not vote to reopen either. It is quite likely that your guess is correct, but it is not certain either. It may also be "With what precision can one compute the answer on a modern computer within an hour?", or almost anything else. I just object to using the "Not interesting" stamp *before* getting certain about what is asked, that's all.

Comment: @fedja: I take your point.  In general I am happy to give questions the benefit of doubt.  But it is also the responsibility of the asker to write a clear question.  Even if the question is closed, OP could edit it and clarify why this would be research level; the help center gives directions to do so when a question is closed.  So I find it difficult to feel too guilty about closing if no effort is made to improve the question.

Comment: @Lucia "it is also the responsibility of the asker to write a clear question." I do not disagree at all here (just look at what I wrote in my "profile") :-)

Comment: @fedja:  Indeed! :)  One final comment:  Like you, I could also make the substitution $x\to x^2$, but WolframAlpha does a little bit more.  It computes the integral to more than $50$ digits, and will make some attempt to find a ``closed form" if you type in a real number.  I did try that, and it didn't turn up any simple relation to nice numbers (unsurprisingly).